# Passing resolving container to a resolved type

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I am using [Unity.MVC3](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) and [Unity.WCF](http://unitywcf.codeplex.com/).  Using these packages, you register types with a parent container, then Controllers / Services are created with a child container.  Types registered with a `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` are limited to one instance per request.

I am running into an issue with my classes that take an `IUnityContainer` as a constructor parameter.  I register these like this.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new InjectionConstructor(container));
```

This causes Foo to be created with an reference to the parent container, not the child container.  If I then resolve a type that was registered with a `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`, I will get a second instance.  Additionally, this instance will not be disposed with the child container.

Is there a way to register my types such that they will receive the child container used to resolve them?

Comment: Why do you want to inject the container into your classes? Usually this indicates an application of the ServiceLocator which is [considered an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) in modern software architecture.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it an anti pattern if injecting the container into a factory class.

Comment: @jrummell If the factory class is located in the scope of the composition root ... maybe. Mark Seemann has a nice [article about that topic](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementingAnAbstractFactory.aspx) in his blog. But then I would not write the factory class at all but let [Unity generate it](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Auto-generated%20Factories%20with%20Unity&referringTitle=Home).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object has a dependency of type IUnityContainer, it'll automatically get injected with the resolving container. You don't need to configure anything, it'll just work.

Comment: I just discovered this.  I am in the middle of testing right now to make sure I get the expected behavior.

Comment: Yup, it works.  I knew there had to be an easy way to do it.  I just didn't realize how easy it was.